# How to install Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2

I have tried to install `magento 2.2` version in my `localhost`.

But when I complete whole steps home page shows blank screen.

So Can some one help me into this ?

Comment: plz add your screenshot for debug more your current issue.

Comment: Without any more info, it's hard to help out. Could you check your error logs? `/var/log/[apache2 or nginx/error.log`, and the error logs from Magento (`var/log/system.log`, `var/log/support_report.log` or `var/log/exception.log`)?